# Android Web-View shouldOverrideUrlLoading() Deprecated.(Alternative)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I have Found a method to make mailto work in android webview but the method is deprecated.Can any one give me full code snippet of the new method.
Here is the method I found on this site

**Java** code is below:

```
@Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

     if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
         initiateCall(url);
         return true;
      }
       if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
         sendEmail(url.substring(7));
         return true;
      }
         return false;
  }
```

But it's not working when I have target platform as Android 7.1.1

Comment: Did you look at the Android docs?  They have a link to the replacement function right there.  boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, 
                WebResourceRequest request)

Comment: Yes,Gabe Sechan I visited android docs .but as I am a newbie I didn't the replacement function completely. so I am asking for the code snippet

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Gabe .I called my self newbie because I am a mechanical engineering student trying to create a app for my website.There is no one near to me to teach coding.I completely depend on free internet sources to learn.

Comment: @MVenkatNaidu check my answer..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Android N and above has this method signature:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

> The one that is supported by all Android versions has this method signature:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

> What should I do to make it work on all versions?
>
> you need to override both the methods

For every api including `Android N+` you need to change your code.

Check this below code. It will target both lower API with `N` and above

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
        initiateCall(url);
        return true;
    }
    if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
        sendEmail(url.substring(7));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    String url = request.getUrl().toString();
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
        initiateCall(url);
        return true;
    }
    if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
        sendEmail(url.substring(7));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```